# Equivalent PostgreSQL query from SQLite

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I'm a mobile developer, but I've been doing some server work lately, so please excuse my terminology etc. I've been running into what might (??) be a difference between SQLite (which is what I use on iOS/Android) and PostgreSQL (which I use in APIs).

In SQLite, I could `SELECT *` from a table and then `GROUP BY` a single column without any aggregate functions at all. However, in PostgreSQL, it keeps complaining that it needs columns in the group by or an agg function.

Suppose I have a `stop_times` table which has these columns: `stop_id`, `trip_id`, `stop_sequence`, and `departure_time`. My `trips` table has a `trip_id` column and `route_id`. In SQLite, I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "stop_times" 
  INNER JOIN "trips" ON "stop_times"."trip_id" = "trips"."trip_id" 
  WHERE "stop_times"."stop_id" IN (?, ?, ?) 
  GROUP BY "stop_times"."stop_id", "trips"."route_id"
```

(I'm trying to determine the `stop_sequence`s of a particular set of stops along any routes that stop at them.) In PostgreSQL, however, this doesn't appear to work, as it complains until I put every column of `stop_times` into either the group by clause or an aggregate function. When I do, what I get back from the db is useless (in Rails, it's just a bunch of empty objects: `#<StopTime >`).

How can I achieve the same thing as above, but with Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match column list with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT "stop_times"."stop_id", "trips"."route_id" 
FROM "stop_times" 
INNER JOIN "trips" ON "stop_times"."trip_id" = "trips"."trip_id" 
WHERE "stop_times"."stop_id" IN (?, ?, ?) 
GROUP BY "stop_times"."stop_id", "trips"."route_id"
```

or `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON("stop_times"."stop_id", "trips"."route_id") *
FROM "stop_times" 
INNER JOIN "trips" ON "stop_times"."trip_id" = "trips"."trip_id" 
WHERE "stop_times"."stop_id" IN (?, ?, ?)
```